# Некорректно отображаются русские символы в VS Code Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Недавно начал изучение Java и столкнулся с проблемой. В VS Code, в консоли, русские буквы дублируются и некорректно отображаются.
При использовании этого кода.

```
    public class App {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Привет, Мир!");
            System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
```

В консоль выводится это.

```
    Привет, Мир!
    Мир!
    !
    Hello, World!
```

При использовании Python, в этом же редакторе, все нормально(Как другие языки не знаю).
В обычной консоли результат еще хуже.
(Если это понадобится, то использую Windows 7, версия Java version 8)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю сильно ли поможет: у меня была подобная проблема с Интелидж когда я поменял кодировку в ней с UTF-8 на другую.... слышал так же что на это может влиять язык системы но насколько это правда - не знаю

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: да, я это понимаю, но так как оставлять комментарии я не могу, а набрать 50 БР я вряд ли смогу в течении нескольких минут - пришлось написать свой вариант решения именно таким образом... Очень хотел помочь человеку с его проблемой, ведь я и сам только изучаю Java и очень во многом полагаюсь на помощь других людей

Comment: Кодировку менял на UTF-16 и на другие менее популярные кодировки. Язык системы менять не хотелось бы. Буду искать решение дальше, а пока все буде на английском делать.

Comment: Удачи, могу ещё только посоветовать использовать IntelliJ IDE ну или Eclipse